# Button to delete individual data not working.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've scraped products from a website and inserted them into my DB.  All the products are being listed properly on my View page, but I can't seem to get the delete button to work.  The reason there are repeats in my rake routes is that I initially wrote the routes out manually but then used

```
resources :ibotta
```

I just tried moving the "resources :ibotta" to the top of the routes, but that didn't work.  When I click the "Destroy" button, the link it takes me to is

"https://rails-tutorial2-chriscma.c9users.io/ibotta.14738"

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

**View**

```
<h1>Show Page for iBotta</h1>

<h3><%= @products.length %> products in the iBotta DB</h3>

<% @products.each do |x| %>
    <p>Title: <a href=<%=x.link%>><%= x.title %></a> </p> 
    <p>Value: <%= x.values %> </p>
    <p>Store: <%= x.store %> </p>

    <%= link_to 'Destroy', ibotta_path(x.id),
              method: :delete %>

<% end %>
```

**Method in Controller**

```
def destroy
    Ibotta.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to ibotta_path
end
```

**Rake Routes**

```
              ibotta_save GET    /ibotta/save(.:format)                   ibotta#save
              ibotta_show GET    /ibotta/show(.:format)                   ibotta#show
            ibotta_delete GET    /ibotta/delete(.:format)                 ibotta#delete

                   ibotta GET    /ibotta(.:format)                        ibotta#index
                          POST   /ibotta(.:format)                        ibotta#create
              new_ibottum GET    /ibotta/new(.:format)                    ibotta#new
             edit_ibottum GET    /ibotta/:id/edit(.:format)               ibotta#edit
                  ibottum GET    /ibotta/:id(.:format)                    ibotta#show
                          PATCH  /ibotta/:id(.:format)                    ibotta#update
                          PUT    /ibotta/:id(.:format)                    ibotta#update
                          DELETE /ibotta/:id(.:format)                    ibotta#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just passing your object and using the delete method to make a DELETE request, like:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <p>Title: <%= link_to product.title, product.link %></p> 
  <p>Value: <%= product.values %></p>
  <p>Store: <%= product.store %></p>

  <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

In case of creating an `a` tag, you can use the `link_to` Rails helper.

---

As I saw in your project, you don't have a `layouts/application.html.erb` file, that's why everything you render isn't passing by the `yield` in this file, and you're not adding nothing in your application.js or css file, so, you don't have jQuery nor jQuery UJS. This makes everytime you click on the anchor tag to delete such element, to perform a GET request, no matter if you're specifying the method to use.

This can be solved by adding the folder and file, as with any project, with the initial structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Note if you do it, you need to comment the content in your `javascripts/ibotta.coffee`, otherwise you'll get the error:

> SyntaxError: [stdin]:6:8: unexpected @

And I'm not sure why.

Or if you prefer to continue without this file (which I don't recommend), you can easily just to change your `link_to` helper, for a `button_to` helper, like:

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', x, method: :delete %>
```

What'll give tou a different html structure, but works on deleting the records:

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/ibotta/id">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
  <input type="submit" value="Destroy">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="token">
</form>
```

Note you have a destroy and delete method in your controller, I guess the one you need is `destroy`, which is used by your `resources` routes.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/hnhm/ibotta) is the repository where you can see it working.

Comment: I've tweaked a little bit the example, to make it more expressive, but you're using x here `@products.each do |x|`, so you could do `<%= link_to 'Destroy', x, method: :delete %>`.